# get session data in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

I'm new to rails coming from php, and I'm learning rails 3 with mongodb.

I have got to the point where I have an html form post text to mongo, and i can create and login as a user.

In the user login, i create a session with as created by nifty authenticate

```
session[:user_id] = user.id
```

now I'm trying to get that user_id from the session when I create a new post so that the post is connected to the user.

in my posts_controller, I have the create function as follows.

```
def create
    @post = Post.new(params[:post])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
        format.html { redirect_to(@post, :notice => 'Post was successfully created.') }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @post, :status => :created, :location => @post }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @post.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
end
```

however, i believe I need to pass the user_id in here, or maybe it would be better to put it in my model.

But attempting any sort of

```
@user_id = session[:user_id]
```

hasn't returned anything meaningful. Am I going about this the wrong way?

I've seen posts which describe storing sessions in the database, but I don't really see why this should be necessary for something as simple as just getting the currently logged-in user_id.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just looking to keep track of the user who created the post in your post db? Within the post model a simple:

> belongs to: user

should work. As long as you have a user_id field in your post db as well
(I'm not exactly sure if this is what you were asking for.)

Comment: Thanks mike, that actually does solve the problem at this instance (I was doing both belongs_to AND storing the user_id as a key). 

However, I'm sure I'll want to get the user from a session at some point in the future. 

I guess part of my question now is how does the post model know which user is the currently logged in one?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the docs: [Nifty Authentication](http://github.com/ryanb/nifty-generators/blob/master/rails_generators/nifty_authentication/USAGE)

Nifty Authentication includes a method called current_user (most of the authentication solutions for Rails follow the same naming convention) that will do exactly as it says, get the current user. So, you could do the following:

```
post.user = current_user
```

*EDIT* This can be done only after you create the proper relationship as detailed by Mike.